# Converting over 24 hours into Date_Time

Tags: r

I have a data frame of cross channel swimming times. These range from 6:35:00 to `43:00:00+`. When I try and convert to date time using:

```
 as.POSIXlt(as.character(swims$times)
```

**R** returns `NAs` for the times greater than `23:59:59`.

I have tried searching online etc. but have not found a solution.

What is the best way of handling this?

Pierre here is a sample of the data

UniqueID     Time

1 187500001 21:45:00

2 191100001 22:35:00

3 192300001 26:50:00

4 192300002 16:33:00

5 192300003 16:58:00

6 192600001 14:39:00

nrussell: what would you suggest instead of POSIXt?

Comment: Do you have any sample data to better see what you're working with?

Comment: Why do you want to convert these to `POSIXt` objects? IMO what they represent (time duration) is fundamentally different from what the `POSIXlt` or `POSIXct` classes represent (calendar dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) package has a duration type.  You can convert your times to a duration that can then work in conjunction with dates.

In this case you can convert the time listed as hours:minutes:seconds to seconds and coerce using:

```
library(lubridate)
as.duration(as.double(substr(swim$time,1,2)) * 3600 + as.double(substr(swim$time,4,5)) * 60)
```